# When does isomorphic simplicial homology imply homeomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

It is known that if $X_1,X_2$ are homeomorphic then their homology groups are isomorphic. What conditions are needed on $X_1,X_2$ such that if their homology groups are isomorphic, then it implies a homeomorphism exists between $X_1,X_2$?

Comment: I doubt there is any nice general condition.  Homeomorphism is a vastly stronger condition than having isomorphic homology.

Comment: A better question to ask is "when homotopy-equivalence implies existence of a homeomorphism." At least, there is a conjecture in this direction.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you. Could you please point me towards the conjecture?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_conjecture

Answer (score 3):

Isomorphic homology groups do not imply that the corresponding spaces are homeomorphic, even if you restrict to the nicest possible class of spaces. All $\mathbb R^n$ are contractible, hence have vanishing homology, but there is no homeomorphism $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ for $n \neq m$.

But in a sense, homeomorphism is not the right property to ask for. Note that homology is invariant under homotopies, hence a "better" question to ask would be if isomorphic homology implies homotopy equivalence between spaces. But this is also not always true (see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53399/spaces-with-same-homotopy-and-homology-groups-that-are-not-homotopy-equivalent/53410?_gl=1*1iiwz4q*_ga*MTIzMDkwMDQwMC4xNjczNDM0Njky*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY3NTA4MjcwMi4yMS4xLjE2NzUwODMzNjUuMC4wLjA.#53410)). If we restrict to sufficiently nice classes of spaces, we have the following result:

> [Whitehead] A map $f : X \to Y$ between simply connected CW-complexes is a homotopy equivalence, if $f_* : H_n(X) \to H_n(Y)$ is an isomorphism for every $n$.

Note that it is not sufficient for this theorem that the $H_n$ are isomorphic, but that $f$ induces the respective isomorphisms.